# Spring Integration Bridge - Request Headers

Tags: spring-integration, bridge, request-headers

I have a SI application that uses Bridge to bridge some channels. I want the request headers to be copied through the bridge. When I debugged the application, I found that the BridgeHandler has a method which sets copyRequestHeaders() to false. 
    public class BridgeHandler extends AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler {

```
@Override
public String getComponentType() {
    return "bridge";
}

@Override
protected Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> requestMessage) {
    return requestMessage;
}

@Override
protected boolean shouldCopyRequestHeaders() {
    return false;
}
}
```

I want to change this to keep it true. I looked up Bridge's XSD and it doesnt seem to support any entry to alter this, nor does it take a reference to a custom bridge handler bean.

What are my options now? Any suggestions would be helpful.

spring-config.xml:

```
<beans:import resource="classpath*:spring/rabbit.xml" />
<beans:import resource="classpath*:spring/router.xml" />
<beans:import resource="classpath*:spring/file_persister.xml" />
<beans:import resource="classpath*:spring/transformer.xml" />   

<!-- Rabbit to Router -->
<int:bridge id="rabbitBridge" input-channel="rabbitInboundChannel" output-
channel="routerInputChannel" />
```

rabbit.xml:

```
<int:channel id="rabbitInboundChannel" />
<rabbit:connection-factory id="amqpConnectionFactoryInbound" 
 host="${rabbit.host}" port="${rabbit.port}"
 username="${rabbit.username}" password="${rabbit.password}" channel-cache-
 size="${rabbit.channelCacheSize}"
 connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactoryInbound" />

 <beans:bean id="rabbitConnectionFactoryInbound" 
   class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
     <beans:property name="requestedHeartbeat" 
             value="${rabbit.requestedHeartBeat}" />
 </beans:bean>

 <!-- Inbound Adapter to AMQP RabbitMq -->
 <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="rabbitMQInboundChannelAdapter" 
    channel="rabbitInboundChannel" concurrent-
    consumers="${rabbit.concurrentConsumers}" task-executor="rabbit-
    executor" connection-factory="amqpConnectionFactoryInbound"
    message-converter="byteArrayToStringConverter" queue-
    names="${rabbit.queue}" error-channel="errorChannelId"
    prefetch-count="${rabbit.prefetchCount}" />

 <header-enricher input-channel="rabbitInboundChannel" output-
      channel="rabbitLoggingChannel">
             <int:header name="Operation" value="${operation.rabbit}" overwrite="true" />
            **<int:header name="GUID" expression="#{ 'T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()' }" />**
            <int:header name="operationStartTime" expression="#{ 'T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis()' }" />
  </header-enricher>

 <int:channel id="rabbitLoggingChannel">
  <int:interceptors>
    <int:wire-tap channel="loggerChannel" />
  </int:interceptors>
 </int:channel> 

 <task:executor id="rabbit-executor" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" pool-
          size="${rabbit.poolSize}" queue-capacity="${rabbit.queueSize}" />
```

router.xml:

```
<int:channel id="routerInputChannel" />
 <int:header-enricher input-channel="routerInputChannel" output-
   channel="routerLoggingChannel">
 <int:header name="Operation" value="${operation.router}" overwrite="true" 
    />
 <int:header name="file_name" expression="headers['GUID'] + '.xml'" />
 <int:header name="operationStartTime" expression="#{ 
       'T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis()' }" overwrite="true" />
 <int:error-channel ref="errorChannelId" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int:recipient-list-router id="recipientListRouter" input-
        channel="routerInputChannel">
    <int:recipient channel="filePersistChannel" selector-expression="new 
          String(payload).length()>0" />
    <int:recipient channel="transformerInputChannel" />
</int:recipient-list-router>

<int:channel id="routerLoggingChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="loggerChannel" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
```

Logging O/P:

```
2017-04-24 13:26:33,360 [rabbit-executor-4] INFO 
       Operation="RABBIT_INBOUND_ADAPTER" Status="Success" DurationMs="0" 
       GUID="8d5c67c8-a0fb-4a7e-99dc-f545159dde7e"   
2017-04-24 13:26:33,361 [rabbit-executor-4] INFO Operation="ROUTER" 
       Status="Success" DurationMs="0" GUID=" "   
2017-04-24 13:26:33,364 [rabbit-executor-4] INFO Operation="FILE_PERSISTER" 
       Status="Success" DurationMs="3" GUID=" "   
2017-04-24 13:26:33,381 [rabbit-executor-5] INFO 
       Operation="ORDER_EVENT_TRANSFORMER" Status="Success" DurationMs="27" 
       GUID=" "
```

If you notice, the GUID header which gets set in rabbit.xml is not propogated to router.xml, hence the log has empty GUID. Without the bridge, the GUID gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that. The `<bridge>` is based on the `BridgeHandler` which logic is very transparent:

```
@Override
protected Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> requestMessage) {
    return requestMessage;
}
```

So, it is obvious - your request headers are transferred, just because the whole `requestMessage` travels to the `outputMessage`.

The logic behind that method is like:

```
protected Message<?> createOutputMessage(Object output, MessageHeaders requestHeaders) {
    AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?> builder = null;
    if (output instanceof Message<?>) {
        if (!this.shouldCopyRequestHeaders()) {
            return (Message<?>) output;
        }
        builder = this.getMessageBuilderFactory().fromMessage((Message<?>) output);
    }
    else if (output instanceof AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder) {
        builder = (AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?>) output;
    }
    else {
        builder = this.getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(output);
    }
    if (this.shouldCopyRequestHeaders()) {
        builder.copyHeadersIfAbsent(requestHeaders);
    }
    return builder.build();
}
```

Since our `output` is `Message` and we don't `copyRequestHeaders()`, nothing is changed and everything is good for you.

I wonder what makes you to come to us with such an issue, because there is just no issue.

## confused

Comment: My bridge is from ChannelA to ChannelB. When the message goes to ChannelA, I do a header-enricher and I add a new header. When the message goes to ChannelB through the above method of createOutputMessage(), I dont see the new header in the Request Headers, my assumption was shouldCopyRequestHeaders() was not copying it for me. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: OK! Share, please the whole test-case to play from our side. That really isn't possible... You might have something else in-between

Comment: I have added some sample code. Please let me know if you have any questions there.

In the createOutputMessage() code sample that you have pasted, the message is sent as it is to output channel only **if (!this.shouldCopyRequestHeaders())** since the method returns 'false' by default, new message is always built, which looses the message headers. This is my understanding.

Comment: Well, that isn't so helpful because too many code. What I see that you have several subscribes as for `rabbitInboundChannel`, as well as for the `routerInputChannel`. Since they are `DirectChannel`s the messages are handled to the target subscribes via `round-robin` manner. That may be how it confuses you because sometime message just don't go to the proper component. I guess header-enricher in your case.

Comment: ??? `if (!this.shouldCopyRequestHeaders()) {  return (Message<?>) output; }` What am I missing? Where do you see a new message in this clause ?

Comment: It looks like when the message goes to rabbitInboundChannel, the headers get added and logged. When the message is handed-off to routerInputChannel, the BridgeHandler's **protected Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> requestMessage)** method's requestMessage doesn't preserve any of the headers enriched before. So, `if (!this.shouldCopyRequestHeaders()) { return (Message<?>) output; }` returns the same message which has no headers. 
Is there any other place in between where the message would have been built to loose the headers?

Comment: You don't follow my comments. If you have several subscribers to the `DirectChannel`, only one of them will have that message, in round-robin manner. Consider to place header-enricher in between AMQP channel adapter and bridge. Plus bare in mind that messages are **immutable** by default. And that means that after header-enricher you have a new fresh message. The input one is without modifications. Seems for me we have all of that information in the Reference Manual.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142550/discussion-between-preethi-r-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: It looks like my code was throwing an exception for **rabbitLoggingChannel** that there are no subscribers. So at this time, the message headers get lost. I fixed it by adding another channel as a subscriber to the channel.